# Is it possible to connect to another database during an alembic migration upgrade?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am performing a standard alembic migration on `Database A`, however, there is a table in `Database B` I will need to query during my upgrade. Is it possible to connect to `Database B` to query and retrieve the result during the upgrade on `Database A`? db `A` does not live on the same server as `B`.